# React : UI Data is not updated in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, ecmascript-6

I am working on ReactJS project , Where I am showing data through API . Actually REST call is working fine when I see it URL filter data is showing but UI is not updated when I refresh the browser UI has been updated . I am new to ReactJS could someone please help me how to solve this problem .

Thanks

**Code**

```
 class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or it will be very hard for someone to help you.

Comment: @Tholle , I just updated my question please have a look and I am beginner please help me

Comment: That's alright. Please read the link I sent you in my last comment. Try to boil down the issue you are having to use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.

Comment: @Tholle , Actually I have an issue with that code which about 10-15 lines . I have updated question based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to drop componentWillUpdate first and foremost, as that's been declared unsafe.  However you can try componentDidUpdate.  This should take care of this issue.  You could also use the useEffect hook, which basically acts as componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
console.log(prevProps, this.props)
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.parties !== prevProps.parties) {
    this.setState({
    data: props.parties,
    renderData:props.parties
  });
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm slightly confused about the question but it could be a setState problem. State is usually one step behind render unless you make a callback after setState, i.e. in the section where you write:

```
this.setState({
    data: nextProps.parties,
    renderData:nextProps.parties
  });
```

try

```
this.setState({
    data: nextProps.parties,
    renderData:nextProps.parties
  }, () => {});
```

Comment: It not working , could you please help me with another solution ?

Comment: Not even lakerskill's answer? I agree with his point of using the new React hook 'useEffect', you don't really have to go through the hassle of creating class components and just use functional components with useState and useReducer hooks to create your own state management. 

Hate to tell you to rewrite code but I think it'll be much easier and clean for you in the long run. Check it out:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.htm

Comment: If I would have had useEffect months ago, I wouldn't know what componentDidUpdate does lol.